# What does "JPRT" means in OpenJDK

Tags: java

I'm looking for where the version information is stored in OpenJDK source tree and noticed the file "make/jprt.properties" has some relevant information there.
What does JPRT means in that context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPRT is a jenkins plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/jprt

OpenJDK builds probably are tested using jenkins with JPRT plugin 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/jprt-plugin

It's mentioned also in java ("JPRT control builds/jprt control jobs"):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u4-140071.html
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8130092

Comment: (I think that that Jenkins plugin is for launching / running JPRT.  My reading of the code is that the real JPRT is something separate.)

Comment: No, this is just guess-work. For the correct answer, see Dalibor's reply.

Answer (score 3):

JPRT is an internal OpenJDK build and test system at Oracle. For example, the Oracle Hotspot team uses it to ensure that proposed changes for HotSpot build and pass a core set of tests on a set of core platforms. You can learn more about it here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2014-September/015259.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Dalibor is working at Oracle and knows about the JPRT system.